# After publishing to server (1and1), I can't log in (try to create master error), ASP.NET 4.0

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-membership

1- I have a website, codded with the visual studio 2012 templates. I've not implemented Entity framework (but i could see references to it on the web.config).

2- On localhost running, also Membership (log in and signup) and other forms (with getting data, updating and writing onto database) are working great.

3- Since I have uploaded my website files and my Database tables and store procedure I CAN ACCESS MY DATA TABLES (doing every actions on them) but I CAN'T LOG IN or SIGN UP.

4- I am using the asp.net membership interface.

5- When trying to log in I am getting the following error : "CREATE DATABASE permission denied in database 'master'." 
Any idea? Thanks a lot!

Comment: Look like something wrong with the connection string; it is not using correct database.

Comment: Create database error looks like Entity Framework wants to create a database...